# Is it possible to model a logical OR without boolean variables in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, boolean-logic

I want to state a linear model where I can't use boolean variables due to efficiency reasons. I can only use a solver that can handle boolean variables not that efficiently. And in a productive model I would need hundreds of those variables.

I use a boolean variable to decide if I can satisfy demand either from one source (continuous variable A) or another source (continuous variable B) but not both. 
The constraint is:

A + B >= demand

But either A OR B can be non-zero.
This can be ensured by using a boolean variable (Bool_A) and the following constraints:

A <= 1000 * Bool_A

B <= 1000 * (1- Bool_A)

If Bool_A = 1, then the variable A can take non-zero values and B is forced to 0, and if Bool_A = 0 then vice versa.

My question is now: does anyone know, if it is possible to model this using only linear variables (no booleans and integer variables) or has a proof that it is not possible.

Comment: Proof: use convexity ("or" is non-convex so can never be implemented in a pure LP)

Comment: Erwin, thanks for this! Great hint to look for the convexity! I could not see the forest for the trees and did not think that convexity is the key!

Answer (score 1):

In Brown, G. and Dell, R., "[Formulating linear and integer linear programs: A rogues’ gallery](http://faculty.nps.edu/dell/docs/Brown_Dell_INFORMS_Transactions_on_Education_January2007.pdf)" the following linear programming formulation for the `XOR` (exclusive or) can be found :

```
X = A xor B
```

resolves to

```
X ≤ A + B
X ≥ A - B
X ≥ - A + B
X ≤ 2 - A - B
```

Using an auxiliary variable:

```
X = A + B - 2*H
H ≤ A
H ≤ B
H ≥ A + B - 1
H ≥ 0
```

Comment: This assumes binary variables.

Comment: Axel, I tried it out and it assumes that the variables are binary, unfortunately. Still thanks for the answer and the modelling of XOR. I might not use it this time but especially the paper you referred will be helpful in the future!